# ORA-00905 SSIS 2010 OLEDB though statement works in SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oracle, ssis

hope the title is good enough to freeze the reader, the pseudo code is below

```
    "SELECT DISTINCT TO_NCHAR(ID)
          , DATE
          , OPEN_DATE
          , NUMBER
          , X
          , PRODUCT
          , DESCRIPTION
          , D4
          , TO_NCHAR(CUSTOMERNAME)
       FROM CASE
 INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CASE.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMERS.ID
      WHERE CASE.DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE( '" +  Dts.Variables["start_date"].Value.ToString() + "', 'yyyy/mm/dd')"
          ;
```

Q: if the Oracle SQL Developer is reading, running, not showing error at all, when I pass the code in the VB variable, why does it, misses a char?

It not a complex error, actually i was blaming the TO_NCHAR function, but i tested, as i said.

Comment: `why does it, misses a char` what character is it missing? Given your string concatenation, what does the resulting query look like?

Comment: The statement lacks a second date in the where clause's `between` condition . If handled as a string literal, the nested double quotes might become an issue too. Also some table and column names are sql keywords ( table `CASE`; columns `DATE`, `NUMBER` ), that might  cause trouble either.

Comment: thanks collapsar, for reading, this is pseudo code, in the case of tables and columns but the SQL should be read as Oracle.

Comment: after viewing extra cat-videos, for the change-focus, I checked everything again and seems there is an issue with some comma, i do not know..error Description: "ORA-00911: invalid character" Code:
     `"SELECT DISTINCT TO_NCHAR(ID)
          , DATE
          , OPEN_DATE
          , NUMBER
          , X
          , PRODUCT
          , DESCRIPTION
          , D4
          , TO_NCHAR(CUSTOMERNAME)
       FROM CASEINNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CASE.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMERS.ID
      WHERE CASE.DATE >= TO_DATE( '" +  Dts.Variables["start_date"].Value.ToString() + "', 'yyyy/mm/dd')"
          ;`

Comment: Removed the Script task and used the plain SQL command and worked. Code:
     `SELECT DISTINCT TO_NCHAR(ID), 
    DATE, OPEN_DATE,
    NUMBER,
    X,
    PRODUCT, 
    DESCRIPTION, 
    D4, 
    TO_NCHAR(CUSTOMERNAME)
    FROM CASE 
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CASE.CUSTOMERID =     CUSTOMERS.ID WHERE CASE.DATE >= TO_DATE( '2015-19-02', 'YYYY-DD-MM')`

Comment: Change column names DATE and NUMBER to something other, like CDATE, CNUMBER. `date` and `number` are Oracle reserved words, you can use them in quotation marks `"`, but it's better to avoid it. Also I'd change table name from `CASE`, to something other e.g. `CASES`, because `case` is part of Oracle syntax.

Comment: sorry, Ponder for the bad pseudocode but i am not running these words in the SQL. However the query it is running in Oracle SQL developer, in SQL command choice. Why is not passing the sql statement from Script Task to SQL variable drop-down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final pseudocode running in the variable is the following;

```
`User::sql_statement  //Locals  
{
SELECT DISTINCT TO_NCHAR(ID), DATE, OPEN_DATE,NUMBER,X,PRODUCT,            
PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, D4, TO_NCHAR(CUSTOMERNAME) FROM CASES INNER JOIN                                   
CUSTOMERS ON     CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMERSID 
WHERE DATE >= TRUNC(TO_DATE( '2/18/2015 9:53:00 AM', 'YYYY-DD-MM'))
 }  String      //Locals`
```

Thanks!!! for few follow ups, see ya later...